# How to extract multiple text elements from a HTML class using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the sample HTML code (from imdb.com) I want to extract text elements from:

```
<p class="">
    Director:
<a href="/name/nm0001104/">Frank Darabont</a>
<span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm0000209/">Tim Robbins</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0000151/">Morgan Freeman</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0348409/">Bob Gunton</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0006669/">William Sadler</a>
</p>
```

From it, I can extract the director, but can't seem to do that for the stars.

I am extracting the director with this:

```
<html_code>.find('a').text
```

How can I extract the names of the actors (Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler) using similar syntax?

A beginner in BeautifulSoup thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `<html_code>.find_all('a')`

Comment: I want to extract them separately as two lists - one list for directors and the other for the stars. Later these lists should be converted into pandas Series.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the HTML is consistent, you can use `find_all` instead:

```py
director, *cast = <html_code>.find_all('a')

print("Director:", director.text)

print("Cast:")
for actor in cast:
    print(actor.text)
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that a) there is only one director, b) that the structure will always be the same (i.e. director then stars), and c) that the only two sections are Director and Stars

Comment: @TheTechRobotheNerd yes, exactly. But OP can start with my suggestion.

Comment: I know, was just telling OP so they didn't stumble into issues.